# Javascript getUTCDate return the previous day

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

code like this

```
var date = new Date("2012/09/04");
console.log(date.getUTCDate());
//returns 3
```

can someone tell me how to get the correct date based on a time string like yyyy/mm/dd?

thx~

Comment: expecting 4 when i give a string pattern like "2012/9/4"

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use `getUTCxxx` if you're dealing only with dates (i.e. you're not concerned about time). If you create a `Date` object like you did (specifying only the date) it will set the time to `0:00:00`. When converting to UTC, if your timezone is positive it will subtract some time from your date, so your date will represent the previous day.

Instead, I'd suggest just using `getDate` for that.

**Note:** in my machine (I'm at UTC-3) the snippet above runs just fine (i.e. it returns `4`), but that's because `new Date("2012/09/04")` here evaluates at:

```
alert(new Date("2012/09/04"));
// Tue Sep 04 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
alert(new Date("2012/09/04").toUTCString());
// Tue, 04 Sep 2012 03:00:00 GMT
```

If I were at, say, UTC+3 instead, I'd probably get results like:

```
alert(new Date("2012/09/04"));
// Tue Sep 04 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300
alert(new Date("2012/09/04").toUTCString());
// Mon, 03 Sep 2012 21:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tack on `"UTC"` to the end of your string when you pass it to the constructor:

```
function UTCDate(s) {
    return new Date(s + " UTC");
}
```